# Create new elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create new elements with name and time. I want to let the user customize them(ex. can be able to change color).

The dropdown option is only working for the first class it changes the color but the rest of them are not working. How can I fix it?

```js
function f_color() {
  var x = document.getElementById('Tcolor1').value;
  window.alert(x);
  if (x == 0) {
    document.getElementById('input1').style.color = "black";
    document.getElementById('input2').style.color = "black";
    document.getElementById('input3').style.color = "black";
  }
  if (document.getElementById('Tcolor').value == 1) {
    document.getElementById('input1').style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById('input2').style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById('input3').style.color = "red";
  }
  if (document.getElementById('Tcolor').value == 2) {
    document.getElementById('input1').style.color = "blue";
    document.getElementById('input2').style.color = "blue";
    document.getElementById('input3').style.color = "blue";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn2">Add Another Class</button>

 
  <form>

    <select class="form-control" id="Tcolor" name="Tcolor" style="color:black;   
               
           font-size: 20px; " onchange="f_color()">

      <option value=0>black </option>

      <option value=1>red</option>

      <option value=2>blue </option>

    </select>

  </form>

  <form>
    <input id="input1" name="className"><br>
    <input id="input2" name="classTime"><br>
    <input id="input3" name="classNote"><br>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<button id="btn2">Add Another Class</button>

    
    <form>               

     <select class="form-control"  id="Tcolor" name = "Tcolor" style="color:black;   

       font-size: 20px; "  onchange="f_color()"  >   

            <option value=0 >black </option>

            <option value=1 >red</option>

            <option value=2 >blue </option>  

        </select >

    </form>

        <form>
            <input id="input1"   name="className" ><br>
        <input id="input2"   name="classTime" ><br>
        <input id="input3"   name="classNote" ><br>
      </form> 

      <script>
     
          function f_color(){
         var x=document.getElementById('Tcolor1').value; 
          window.alert(x);
        if ( x == 0) {
        document.getElementById('input1').style.color = "black";
        document.getElementById('input2').style.color = "black";
        document.getElementById('input3').style.color = "black";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('Tcolor').value ==  1 ) {
        document.getElementById('input1').style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById('input2').style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById('input3').style.color = "red";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('Tcolor').value ==  2) {
        document.getElementById('input1').style.color = "blue";
        document.getElementById('input2').style.color = "blue";
        document.getElementById('input3').style.color = "blue";
  }
  }
   </script>﻿﻿
```

remove comment

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, `<!-- -->` is not a valid comment tag. Also, in `f_color`, you are using the variable x only once. You should replace your other comparisons with `x` as well. Prefer CSS classes over the style attribute.

Applying all these changes (and a few other miscellaneous changes):

```js
// do it in javascript
document.querySelector(".form-control").onchange = f_color;

function f_color(e) { // e has the calling element in it
  let /*var can be used too*/ x = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
  let input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
  let input2 = document.getElementById("input2");
  let input3 = document.getElementById("input3");
  alert(x);
  let color = "";
  if (x === 0) {
    color = "black";
  } else if (x === 1) {
    color = "red";
  } else if (x === 2) {
    color = "blue";
  }
  alert(color);
  input1.style.color = color;
  input2.style.color = color;
  input3.style.color = color;
}
```

```css
.form-control {
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn2">Add Another Class</button>

<ol>
  <form>

    <select class="form-control" name="Tcolor">
      <option value="0">black</option>
      <option value="1">red</option>
      <option value="2">blue</option>
    </select>

  </form>

  <form>
    <input id="input1" name="className"><br>
    <input id="input2" name="classTime"><br>
    <input id="input3" name="classNote"><br>
  </form>
</ol>
```

---

But really, the problem is the mis-spelling of "Tcolor" in

```
var x = document.getElementById('Tcolor1').value;
```

It should be "Tcolor".-

Comment: Thanks, I have made the changes you mentioned. But after adding a new class, the color is not changeable.

Comment: You need to add that new class to the JavaScript code as well if you want it to change as well. Also, make sure, if you are setting the color property in your class, that it does not have the `!important` specifier on it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function f_color() {
  var x = document.getElementById('Tcolor1').value;
  window.alert(x);
  if (x == 0) {
    document.getElementById('input1').style.color = "black";
    document.getElementById('input2').style.color = "black";
    document.getElementById('input3').style.color = "black";
  }
  if (document.getElementById('Tcolor').value == 1) {
    document.getElementById('input1').style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById('input2').style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById('input3').style.color = "red";
  }
  if (document.getElementById('Tcolor').value == 2) {
    document.getElementById('input1').style.color = "blue";
    document.getElementById('input2').style.color = "blue";
    document.getElementById('input3').style.color = "blue";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn2">Add Another Class</button>

 
  <form>

    <select class="form-control" id="Tcolor" name="Tcolor" style="color:black;   
               
           font-size: 20px; " onchange="f_color()">

      <option value=0>black </option>

      <option value=1>red</option>

      <option value=2>blue </option>

    </select>

  </form>

  <form>
    <input id="input1" name="className"><br>
    <input id="input2" name="classTime"><br>
    <input id="input3" name="classNote"><br>
  </form>
```